Segfault shellcode in main C
I'm trying to create a main. I compiled my code with:
$ gcc -g3 -o shellcode shellcode.c 

But I always get a Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Using GDB, I see that the first instruction is executed correctly, but not the following steps.
pwndbg> b * main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4020
pwndbg> r
────────────────────────────────────────────────────[ DISASM / x86-64 / set emulate on ]─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 ► 0x555555558020 <main>         jmp    main+15                     <main+15>
    ↓
   0x55555555802f <main+15>      call   main+2                      <main+2>

   0x555555558034 <main+20>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558037 <main+23>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558038 <main+24>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x555555558039 <main+25>      sub    al, 0x57
   0x55555555803b <main+27>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x55555555803c <main+28>      jb     0x5555555580aa              <0x5555555580aa>

   0x55555555803e <main+30>      and    dword ptr fs:[rax], eax
   0x555555558041 <completed>    add    byte ptr [rax], al
   0x555555558043                add    byte ptr [rax], al
pwndbg> disass
Dump of assembler code for function main:
=> 0x0000555555558020 <+0>:     jmp    0x55555555802f <main+15>
   0x0000555555558022 <+2>:     push   0x1
   0x0000555555558024 <+4>:     pop    rax
   0x0000555555558025 <+5>:     mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555558028 <+8>:     pop    rsi
   0x0000555555558029 <+9>:     push   0xc
   0x000055555555802b <+11>:    pop    rdx
   0x000055555555802c <+12>:    syscall
   0x000055555555802e <+14>:    (bad)
   0x000055555555802f <+15>:    call   0x555555558022 <main+2>
   0x0000555555558034 <+20>:    rex.W
   0x0000555555558035 <+21>:    gs ins BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
   0x0000555555558037 <+23>:    ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
   0x0000555555558038 <+24>:    outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
   0x0000555555558039 <+25>:    sub    al,0x57
   0x000055555555803b <+27>:    outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
   0x000055555555803c <+28>:    jb     0x5555555580aa
   0x000055555555803e <+30>:    and    DWORD PTR fs:[rax],eax
pwndbg> ni
  0x555555558020 <main>         jmp    main+15                     <main+15>
    ↓
 ► 0x55555555802f <main+15>      call   main+2                      <main+2>
        rdi: 1
        rsi: 0x7fffffffdff8 —▸ 0x7fffffffe26d ◂— '/shellcode'
        rdx: 0x7fffffffe008 —▸ 0x7fffffffe2ba ◂— 'SHELL=/bin/bash'
        rcx: 0x555555557df8 (__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry) —▸ 0x5555555550e0 (__do_global_dtors_aux) ◂— endbr64

   0x555555558034 <main+20>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558037 <main+23>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558038 <main+24>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x555555558039 <main+25>      sub    al, 0x57
   0x55555555803b <main+27>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x55555555803c <main+28>      jb     0x5555555580aa              <0x5555555580aa>

   0x55555555803e <main+30>      and    dword ptr fs:[rax], eax
   0x555555558041 <completed>    add    byte ptr [rax], al
   0x555555558043                add    byte ptr [rax], al
pwndbg> ni

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x555555558020 <main>         jmp    main+15                     <main+15>

 ► 0x55555555802f <main+15>      call   main+2                      <main+2>
        rdi: 1
        rsi: 0x7fffffffdff8 —▸ 0x7fffffffe26d ◂— '/shellcode'
        rdx: 0x7fffffffe008 —▸ 0x7fffffffe2ba ◂— 'SHELL=/bin/bash'
        rcx: 0x555555557df8 (__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry) —▸ 0x5555555550e0 (__do_global_dtors_aux) ◂— endbr64

   0x555555558034 <main+20>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558037 <main+23>      insb   byte ptr [rdi], dx
   0x555555558038 <main+24>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x555555558039 <main+25>      sub    al, 0x57
   0x55555555803b <main+27>      outsd  dx, dword ptr [rsi]
   0x55555555803c <main+28>      jb     0x5555555580aa              <0x5555555580aa>

   0x55555555803e <main+30>      and    dword ptr fs:[rax], eax
   0x555555558041 <completed>    add    byte ptr [rax], al
   0x555555558043                add    byte ptr [rax], al

As you can see, the first instruction is executed because we jumped on 0x55555555802f.
I tried using only nop instructions, but the same issue keeps occurring repeatedly.
So someone can help me ? Thanks you

The code you published - is impossible to debug. If you want to write in asm, then write in asm. Do not do a manual compilation of asm code - you will make mistakes.

The code is in the data section, so execution may be disabled. But I don't know why it executed the first instruction.

@WhiteOwl Yes, but I just want to do this for the experience :)

likely main is an array of char in the .data or .rodata segment, and security measures prevent it from running.

try char __attribute__((section(".text"))) main[] = ...

Your code is placed in the part of memory which has no execution rights.
You need to place it in the .text section accommodating executable code.
char __attribute__((section(".text"))) main[] = ....


Thank you ! char __attribute__((section(".text"))) main[] = ... works ! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do it without this attribute ? And why the first instruction is executed ?!

@0___________'s answer is right. This is just an addendum in reply to your comments.
Q.1

is it possible to do it without this attribute?

It's possible to do it without applying __attribute__((section(".text"))) to
the symbol main in the code but not possible to do it without doing something
else that places the definition of main in an executable section of the output
object file.
Another way of doing it without applying __attribute__((section(".text"))) is
simply to rename the section in which main gets defined by default to .text[.suffix], so
that the linker will merge it into the executable .text section of the program.
Using the __attribute__((section(".text"))) solution, as per:
$ cat main.c
[[gnu::section(".text")]] char  main[] = 
 // opcode is for Hello world in asm
"\xeb\x0d\x6a\x01\x58\x48\x89\xc7\x5e\x6a\x0c\x5a\x0f\x05\xff\xe8\xee\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21";

$ gcc -g3 main.c
/tmp/ccvTtjYU.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccvTtjYU.s:6: Warning: ignoring changed section attributes for .text

your shellcode runs like:
$ ./a.out 
Hello,World!Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Without using that attribute:
$ cat main.c
char main[] = 
 // opcode is for Hello world in asm
"\xeb\x0d\x6a\x01\x58\x48\x89\xc7\x5e\x6a\x0c\x5a\x0f\x05\xff\xe8\xee\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21";

$ gcc -g3 -c main.c

your shellcode is compiled by default into the .data section, as you can discover if
you need to by:
$ readelf --syms --wide main.o | egrep \(Ndx\|OBJECT.*main\)
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    12: 0000000000000000    33 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 main
    

where Ndx = 4 is the index of the section defining main and section #4 is:
$ readelf --section-details --wide main.o | egrep '\[\s4\]'
  [ 4] .data
  

If we rename section .data to, say, .text.main:
$ objcopy --rename-section .data=.text.main main.o main-hacked.o

$ readelf --section-details --wide main-hacked.o | egrep '.text'
  [ 3] .text
  [ 4] .text.main

and link:
$ gcc main-hacked.o

then your shellcode runs the same:
$ ./a.out 
Hello,World!Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Unless you've got some unstated objection to applying the section(".text") attribute
to main, that one is the better solution than objcopy because you don't even need to know what section
main would otherwise be defined in. E.g. If your source code was:
$ cat main.c 
char const main[] = 
 // opcode is for Hello world in asm
"\xeb\x0d\x6a\x01\x58\x48\x89\xc7\x5e\x6a\x0c\x5a\x0f\x05\xff\xe8\xee\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21";

as it might well have been, then main would not have been defined in the .data section but in the .rodata section.
Q.2

why the first instruction is executed ?!

That is, even when you had main defined in a non-executable section. Good question.
This is an artefact of running your program under gdb, which inevitably
interferes with it. In that context, if you get the program to flow into an non-executable memory segment, you will get to
execute the first instruction there before the kernel serves you with SIGSEGV.
Here's a clearer illustration:
$ cat die.c
#include <stdlib.h>

[[gnu::section(".data")]] int main(void)
{
    abort();
    return 0;
}

Let's just assemble that:
$ gcc -S die.c

$ cat die.s
    .file   "die.c"
    .text
    .section    .data,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    call    abort@PLT
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE6:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long   1f - 0f
    .long   4f - 1f
    .long   5
0:
    .string "GNU"
1:
    .align 8
    .long   0xc0000002
    .long   3f - 2f
2:
    .long   0x3
3:
    .align 8
4:

Notice that the compiler has rightly insisted on making the .data section
executable - .data,"ax" - because it's assembling a function definition
there. Let's tweak this code like so:
$ sed 's/.data,"ax"/.rodata,"a"/' die.s > die-hack-0.s
$ diff die.s die-hack-0.s 
3c3
<   .section    .data,"ax",@progbits
---
>   .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits

Now we have the same program except that it's in a read-only .rodata section.
Let's link that, saving the mapfile:
$  gcc die-hack-0.s -Wl,-Map=hack-0.map

The mapfile shows:
$ egrep -A6 '^.rodata ' hack-0.map
.rodata         0x0000000000002000       0x11
 *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
 .rodata.cst4   0x0000000000002000        0x4 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o
                0x0000000000002000                _IO_stdin_used
 .rodata        0x0000000000002004        0xd /tmp/cc4gpIND.o
                0x0000000000002004                main
                

that the .rodata section starts at offset 0x2000 with main defined 4 bytes in. And the program headers
show:
$ readelf --program-headers --wide a.out
...[cut]...
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0002d8 0x0002d8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000318 0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000000318 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000628 0x000628 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x000159 0x000159 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000f0 0x0000f0 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x002db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x0000000000003db8 0x000258 0x000260 RW  0x1000
 ...[cut]...

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.gnu.property .note.gnu.build-id .note.ABI-tag .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt 
   03     .init .plt .plt.got .plt.sec .text .fini 
   04     .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame
  ...[cut]... 

that .rodata is the first section mapped into the 3rd LOAD segment (segment index = 04),
which is a read-only segment (Flg = R  ).
Now debug into the program:
$ gdb a.out
...[cut]...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in a.out)
(gdb) b * _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1060
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555060 in _start ()
(gdb) b * __libc_start_main_impl
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7ffff7c2a200: file ../csu/libc-start.c, line 242.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __libc_start_main_impl (main=0x555555556004 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdd68, init=0x0, fini=0x0, rtld_fini=0x7ffff7fca380 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdd58)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:242
warning: 242    ../csu/libc-start.c: No such file or directory
(gdb) b * main
Breakpoint 3 at 0x555555556004
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, 0x0000555555556004 in main ()

Now we're at the start of main, in read-only, non-executable memory, as we can show:
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 585490
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
      0x555555554000     0x555555555000     0x1000        0x0  r--p   /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out
      0x555555555000     0x555555556000     0x1000     0x1000  r-xp   /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out
      0x555555556000     0x555555557000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out
      0x555555557000     0x555555558000     0x1000     0x2000  r--p   /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out
      0x555555558000     0x555555559000     0x1000     0x3000  rw-p   /home/imk/develop/so/scrap/a.out
      0x7ffff7c00000     0x7ffff7c28000    0x28000        0x0  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7c28000     0x7ffff7db0000   0x188000    0x28000  r-xp   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7db0000     0x7ffff7dff000    0x4f000   0x1b0000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7dff000     0x7ffff7e03000     0x4000   0x1fe000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7e03000     0x7ffff7e05000     0x2000   0x202000  rw-p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
      0x7ffff7e05000     0x7ffff7e12000     0xd000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7fa7000     0x7ffff7faa000     0x3000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7fbd000     0x7ffff7fbf000     0x2000        0x0  rw-p   
      0x7ffff7fbf000     0x7ffff7fc3000     0x4000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7fc3000     0x7ffff7fc5000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffff7fc5000     0x7ffff7fc6000     0x1000        0x0  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7fc6000     0x7ffff7ff1000    0x2b000     0x1000  r-xp   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7ff1000     0x7ffff7ffb000     0xa000    0x2c000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7ffb000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x2000    0x36000  r--p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x2000    0x38000  rw-p   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
      0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000    0x21000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0  --xp   [vsyscall]
  

We're currently stopped at 0x0000555555556004 which is 4 bytes into the readonly (r--p) 3rd memory segment in the list,
which is at offset 0x2000 from the start of the a.out image, all as per the mapfile and program headers info.
From here on we'll display the pending instruction before we step into it:
gdb) display/i $pc
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555556004 <main>:   endbr64

That's the first instruction.
(gdb) si
0x0000555555556008 in main ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555556008 <main+4>: push   %rbp

Done, and next up is the second:
(gdb) si

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555556008 in main ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555556008 <main+4>: push   %rbp
(gdb)
...[quit]...

SIGSEGV, after 1 instruction.
Now let's tweak the code again as per die-hack-1.s
$ cat die-hack-1.s 
    .file   "die.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    call    abort@PLT   # only 1 instruction
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE6:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long   1f - 0f
    .long   4f - 1f
    .long   5
0:
    .string "GNU"
1:
    .align 8
    .long   0xc0000002
    .long   3f - 2f
2:
    .long   0x3
3:
    .align 8
4:

Now the one and only instruction in the program is call    abort@PLT. It doesn't matter that it's unprepared to return from the call because it won't return.
Link that and debug in:
$ gcc die-hack-1.s
$ gdb a.out
...[cut]...
Reading symbols from a.out...
(No debugging symbols found in a.out)
(gdb) b * _start
...[all as before up to]...
...
...
Breakpoint 3, 0x0000555555556004 in main ()
(gdb) display/i $pc
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555556004 <main>:   call   0x555555555050 <abort@plt>

Back in read-only, non-executable memory, just about to call abort:
(gdb) si
0x0000555555555050 in abort@plt ()
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x555555555050 <abort@plt>:  endbr64

Done. And immediately that takes us out of the r--p 3rd memory segment into the executable (r-xp) 2nd segment at 0x0000555555555050, so we're
free to carry on executing:
(gdb) b * __GI_abort
Breakpoint 4 at 0x7ffff7c28820: file ./stdlib/abort.c, line 49.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 4, __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:49
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7c28820 <__GI_abort>: endbr64

Now we're right out of a.out in segment 0x7ffff7c28000-0x7ffff7db0000, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6.
Let __GI_abort run:
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=<optimised out>) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
warning: 44 ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x7ffff7c9eb1c <__GI___pthread_kill+284>:    mov    %eax,%r14d
...[quit]...

Dodged SIGSEGV.
We can only pull this off because call   abort@PLT is the first instruction in non-executable memory.
If there is even a nop before it, its SIGSEGV.
But furthermore, this is a gdb-only party-trick. If we just run our program:
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

we don't get to execute even a single non-executable instruction.
Q.Follow Up
Why does GDB do this Wile E. Coyote mid-air stride for one non-executable instruction?
My guess is that it's some internal lookahead artefact. But that's just hand-waving - I really
don't know, and if there's a way to make GDB be more careful I don't know it.

Thank you so much for this amazing response. I'll read it over and over because there's so much information here! I had no idea about [[gnu::section(".text")]]. It's just incredible ! And because I'm curious can I have the documentation of this part ? Thank you so much for your answer again

@Mistraleuh The __attribute__((...)) notation is legacy. The equivalent [[gnu:...]] notation is newer and standardised

Wow, I don't understand... It's in C (with gcc) but it looks like C++ "flags" doesn't it ?

@Mistraleuh The [[gnu:...]] syntax is common GCC's C and C++ compilers both. Probably should
have given you this link instead.

Alright, thank you very much, but does that mean we can change or force compilation options using [[gnu::...]] ?

@Mistraleuh No. You can do exactly the things documented here for functions
and here for variables. These attributes do not equate to
compiler options. They attach properties to a function/variable
that are implementation-defined extensions to those expressible in the standard source language.
